# How can Alt-F4 be disabled in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

As in the title: How can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> be disabled in Windows 7?

Comment: You should probably closes some of your open questions. Otherwise, update your questions with more detail so that other can help. Majority of the user here like to earn rep or badges for the work they have done to help others. Please reward them.

Comment: @SgtOJ: I think you mean "accept" not "close".

Comment: No, some are just unacceptable.

Comment: why do you need that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AutoHotKeys is good but I workarounded it much more simply with a remapping of the windows key with a small utility called [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/2008/12/sharpkeys_30.html). It can simply map F4 to another key with a very intuitive interface.

Comment: This is more low level and performs better than AHK. (+1)

Comment: Works marvelously for physical keyboards.  It does not seem to be working for disabling on-screen keyboard keys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) script:

```
# Remaps Alt+F4 to "no action"
!F4::return
```

Comment: +1: AutoHotkey can even mow your lawn and solve world hunger.

Comment: @surfasb: :) cannot live without it! Currently I'm using it for enhancing CMD.EXE, moving and hiding windows, switching monitors, switching tasks, capturing screens, keyboard logging, ....